# Response BinaryWrite not working on iPad

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I need to write out a file for download from the database. I'm using the following code:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=yourFile.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.BinaryWrite(body);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I have tested jpg, pdf, docx, and zip files and all work on an Android tablet. When I test on an iPad with Safari the only file type that appears to work is a zip file. The other file types don't appear to do anything.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you use the correct content type for each file type?

Comment: I think so. For the examples I listed I'm using: image/jpeg, application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/zip.

Comment: That seems correct (without actually looking them up). Just checking so that you didn't just replace the "pdf" part of it and used types like "application/jpg". :)